# EasyUI - How to calculate two column values in editing tree grid

Tags: jquery-easyui

Could you please help me how to calculate two column values in editing tree grid.

Thank you.

Comment: You can edit/calculate two column values in treegrid in the same way you do in datagrid.. check the "Row Editing in DataGrid" in http://jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php?plugin=DataGrid&theme=default&dir=ltr&pitem=

Comment: please provide your code so the others can easily understand your point and give you a solutions..